# How exactly do select.epoll.poll and select.POLLIN work?

Tags: python, sockets, asynchronous, networking, network-programming

```
import select
import socket

loop = select.epoll()

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8000))
sock.listen(1000)
conn, src = sock.accept()

loop.register(conn.fileno(), select.POLLIN)
while True:
    loop.poll()
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        print('receive nothing')
```

I have this script above, which (I suppose) would never print `"receive nothing"`, because `poll()` registered with `select.POLLIN` should return only when there is indeed something to read from the socket. However, when I

```
> nc localhost 8000
test
```

the script keeps spewing out `"receive nothing"`.

Comment: Your script works fine for me. (python3 on ubuntu 14.04). At least until I give EOF to the `nc`. Then it will spew continuously, because there's no provision for exiting the loop.

Comment: @GilHamilton but shouldn't `poll()` hang indefinitely, since the socket is closed and there is no data to read?

Comment: No. A socket for a dead connection is always readable. This is a signal for you to wake up and dispose of it.

Comment: Another way to think of it is that a successful return from `epoll` (or `poll` or `select`) means that your next call to `recv` won't block (not that the socket is actually "readable").

Comment: see http://scotdoyle.com/python-epoll-howto.html